# I want to remove a `%` from entries in a column to create floats without removing other strings (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a `df` that looks something like this:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 80% | 10% | SP |
| 90% | 0% | SP |
| 90% | 10% | SP |
| 70% | SP | 20% |
| 90% | SP | 0% |

As you can see, the values have a `%` sign appended onto them, I could usually remove this by using a `pd.to_numeric()` function and using `df[col2].str.rstrip('%').astype('float') / 100)` however, I cannot do this because the columns currently contain strings such as `SP` which throws an error when doing this

Any ideas as to how to do this?

Comment: `df.replace('%','', regex=True)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using [applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html)

`df.applymap(lambda x : float(x.strip('%')) / 100 if x.endswith('%') else x)`

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly for what I needed! I had an issue where for whatever reason, it was finding floats making the `endswith()` function not work, but managed to fix this with a check first determining `x` was a string.

Looked like this:
`df.applymap(lambda x : x if isinstance(x, str) == False   else (float(x.strip('%')) / 100  if x.endswith('%') else x))`

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression `replace()` works.  Also did `astype()` for columns that can become fully typed.

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""col1    col2    col3
80% 10% SP
90% 0%  SP
90% 10% SP
70% SP  20%
90% SP  0%"""), sep="\t")

df.replace("^([0-9]+)%$", r".\1", regex=True).astype("float64", errors="ignore")
```

### output

```
 col1 col2 col3
  0.8  .10   SP
  0.9   .0   SP
  0.9  .10   SP
  0.7   SP  .20
  0.9   SP   .0
```